# Input/Output error during installation even with different hard drives

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, live-usb

I know that a lot of people have asked about this but none of the answers I've found work. I was installing Ubuntu and after partitioning and such I get an input/output error when installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have tried swapping cables, memory tests, different hard drives, installing and reinstalling Ubuntu on different USBs from ubuntu.com, and nothing has worked.

Am I doing something wrong or is some of my hardware incompatible? Computer specs are 2 gigs DDR (just DDR not 2 or 3) RAM, a8n-sli premium motherboard, and AMD Athlon 64 X2 3600+.

What could be the issue?

Comment: An 'input/output' error usually indicates a hardware problem, most commonly a faulty storage device (hard drive). Look up how to run a SMART test on your storage devices.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: I did not know about this I will try it

Comment: Also add to your question the type of Ubuntu you are trying to install and from what DVD/USB other.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do a smart test and it will not let me does this mean the hard drive is dead or does it not have this capability (this is a older hard drive), it also fails benchmarks.

Comment: OK I got another hard drive and it worked fine so I know the hard drive has a problem but I would still like to use the first one cause its bigger.